# Is $f(n)=\begin{cases} \frac{n}{2}&\text{if}~n~\text{is even}\\ \frac{-n-1}{2}&\text{if}~n~\text{is odd}\end{cases}$ a bijection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

let f define by :
$$f(n)=\begin{cases} \frac{n}{2}&\text{if}~n~\text{is even}\\ \frac{-n-1}{2}&\text{if}~n~\text{is odd}\end{cases}$$

I would like to show that $f$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$

$$\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}\quad \exists\ !\ m\in \mathbb{N} \mbox{ such that } f(m)=n$$

my goal is to proof that by using proof called in french https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raisonnement_par_analyse-synth%C3%A8se sorry i don't know it in english its contains two steps one called analytic show unique of element and other step show existence of that element

**First step of that proof called : Analytic**

Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ suppose that $\exists\ m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(m)=n$.

we've $f(m)=n$

- $\text{if}~n~\text{is even}$  then $n=\dfrac{m}{2}$ thus $m=2n$
- $\text{if}~n~\text{is odd}$ then $n=\dfrac{-(m-1)}{2}$ thus $m=-1-2n$

then $\begin{cases} m=2n&\text{if}~m~\text{is even}\\  
m=-1-2n &\text{if}~m~\text{is odd}\end{cases}$ This shows that if $m$ exists it's *unique*.

**Second step is synthesis:**

(this step is to ensure that this expression that we found it in first step is appropriate)

Let $\begin{cases} m=2n&\text{if}~m~\text{is even}\\  
m=-1-2n &\text{if}~m~\text{is odd}\end{cases}$
let $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

- $\text{if}~n~\text{is even}$  then $\exists k\in\mathbb{Z} \mbox{such that } n=2k$

i'm stuck here please i'm intersent only in that kind of proof so please no alternative proof Thanks

Comment: Your proof of the analytic step is not correct. The cases you should consider are when $n$ is positive and when $n$ is non-negative.

Comment: I think you're actually done. Given $n$ you have an expression for an $m$ such that $f(m)=n$. So that's the "synthesis" step done.

Comment: @AlexG. by the way what is the name of my proof in english, Thanks

Comment: @Educ You need to define $f(n)=\frac{-n+1}{2}$ for $n$ odd.

Answer (score 0):

Inverse function if $n$ negative then $f^{-1}(n) = 2n+1$ if n is positive $f^{-1}(n)=2n$. It is easily verified that this maps all integers$-0$ to all natural numbers.

Note however the function as phrased in the question is not a bijection because its not surjective. There is not a natural number that get sent to $0$.

Comment: $\Bbb N$ is commonly defined to contain $0$, and in that case $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: If were allowing the natural numbers to include 0 then simply state 0 is even and the inverse function stated hold. Note a function is bijective iff its invertable.

Comment: Yes, I'm not saying that your inverse is incorrect. I'm just pointing out that $f$ is surjective if we take $0 \in \Bbb N$.